# Automatically redirect to sub-domain with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am building a web application in which user is assigned a sub-domain,
Now somehow I am able write an `.htaccess` code which allow me to get sub-domain and also retrive the content from the database.

**.htaccess code :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}kanai.in$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]kanai.in$
RewriteRule ^$ website.php?url=%1 [NC,L]
```

orginal link is `kanai.in/website.php?url=test`
and when I write `test.kanai.in` it is successfully giving the content which is stored in database,

What I want is that `kanai.in/website.php?url=test` should automatically redirect to `test.kanai.in`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule ^website.php$ http://%1.kanai.in? [L,R=301]
```

1. We search for `url` value in query string.
2. We check that we are on `website.php` page.
3. We redirect to the value subdomain and remove query parameters by adding a `?`

Those links might help you :

- [Apache wiki page on how to manipulate the Query String](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)
- [Test your apache htaccess files online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: Web browser says "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer by removing your previous instructions

Comment: I really appreciate your quick help...but it is not working either....when i visit kanai.in/website.php?url=test, it redirects me to test.kanai.in/index.php?url=test

Comment: when i visit [http://test100.kanai.in/](http://test100.kanai.in/) I'm redirected to [http://test100.kanai.in/index.php?url=test3](http://test100.kanai.in/index.php?url=test3) witch makes no sense compared to the instructions given before. So you might have some instructions i'm not aware of in your .htaccess or .php files that forces `url=test3` parameters in the query string.

Comment: You can see a hyperlink at my homepage, it consist of an address kanai.in/website.php?url=test where test is the value taken from database..... I only want the value present in url parameter should become sub domain of the site.

Comment: I have changed the parameter in the address from test3 to test

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, I got the answer,
My htaccess code is correct,
All I have to do is just give it a href link as "http://test3.kanai.in",
So it will redirect to test3.kanai.in and will get the corresponding data from the database.....